# Deserialize JSON string to object list and write to values console

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to stream some markets data from Yahoo Finance.
I have some trouble deserialize the json stream and write it to console.

I've been through several stack overflow questions trying to put something together.

I'm unsure if I got the right code put together since I also have problems writing the result to the console.

My json data from Yahoo looks like this:

```
{
   "ResultSet":{
      "Query":"genmab",
      "Result":[
         {
            "symbol":"GNMSF",
            "name":"Genmab A/S",
            "exch":"PNK",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"OTC Markets",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GE9.F",
            "name":"Genmab A/S",
            "exch":"FRA",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Frankfurt",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GEN.F",
            "name":"GENMAB AS  DK 1",
            "exch":"FRA",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Frankfurt",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GE9.BE",
            "name":"GENMAB AS  DK 1",
            "exch":"BER",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Berlin",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GE9.SG",
            "name":"GENMAB AS Navne Aktier DK 1",
            "exch":"STU",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Stuttgart",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GEN.CO",
            "name":"Genmab A/S",
            "exch":"CPH",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Copenhagen",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GEN.SG",
            "name":"GENMAB AS Navne Aktier DK 1",
            "exch":"STU",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Stuttgart",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GMXAY",
            "name":"Genmab A/S",
            "exch":"PNK",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"OTC Markets",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"GE9.DU",
            "name":"GENMAB AS  DK 1",
            "exch":"DUS",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"Dusseldorf Stock Exchange",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         },
         {
            "symbol":"0MGB.IL",
            "name":"GENMAB A/S GENMAB ORD SHS",
            "exch":"IOB",
            "type":"S",
            "exchDisp":"International Orderbook - London",
            "typeDisp":"Equity"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The code that I've put togeter should create a list of data ojects:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class DataObject
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string exch { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string exchDisp { get; set; }
    public string typeDisp { get; set; }

}

public class RootObject
{
    public DataObject[] resultSet { get; set; }
}

using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
        {
            string _url = "http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=genmab&region=CO&lang=en-US";

            var search = web.DownloadString(_url);

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<RootObject> oRootObject = serializer.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(search);
```

And I'd then like to write the different data to the console

```
foreach (var item in oRootObject)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(oRootObject.???.Value.name);
            }
```

I've tried to DeBug the flow but I can't see any data coming into the Object List.

Thanks
Flemming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After formatting your JSON, I can see that your classes don't quite map to your JSON

I used a really handy tool - http://json2csharp.com to create classes that map to your json:

```
public class Result
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string exch { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string exchDisp { get; set; }
    public string typeDisp { get; set; }
}

public class ResultSet
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ResultSet ResultSet { get; set; }
}
```

You can then do, as you did before:

```
RootObject oRootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(search);
```

Inside `oRootObject` is another object - `ResultSet`
Inside `ResultSet` is the `Result` list - so that is what you want to iterate.
You'lll need to do something like this:

```
foreach (var item in oRootObject.ResultSet.Result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.name);
}
```

Comment: You beat me! The particular issue was that the OP mapped ResultSet as an array, instead of containing the Query, then the Result array

Comment: only saw this when I formatted the json correctly. json2csharp.com helps a lot too!

Comment: Thank you that helped alot.

But how do I access or write the different { get; set; } to the console.

I thought of using a foreach but I can't seem to get the code right.